# JS add active hover item list

Tags: javascript, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have list item

```css
.thumbs {display: flex;}
.thumbs .item {width: 150px; height: 150px; margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid black}
.thumbs .item.active {border: 1px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbs">
  <div class="item active">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

How to hover `.thumbs .item` add active to `item:hover` & clear active item(1).
And if not hover any item stick active item last hover.

same as:

hover `item(2)`: add active `item(2)` - Clear active `item(1)` && If don't hover any item or hover out `.thumbs` element stick active item(2).

I user js hover active but not hover clear all active.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thumbs .item").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        $( this ).removeClass('active');
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forgot before add `active` class remove all the class and then add it to current element:

```
$(".item").removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

And for last item use `mouseout` event for `.thumbs`. You need to keep last `Element` when an element unhovered (`lastElemtHoverd = $(this);`)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastElemtHoverd;

    $(".thumbs").mouseout(function () {
        lastElemtHoverd.addClass('active');
    });

    $(".thumbs .item").hover(
        function () {
            $(".item").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            lastElemtHoverd = $(this);
        }
    );
});
```

```css
.thumbs {
    display: flex;
}

    .thumbs .item {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: 1px solid black
    }

        .thumbs .item.active {
            border: 1px solid red
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbs">
        <div class="item active">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to hover out `.thumb` stick active a .item hover?

Comment: @DinhCode this is part of your question. you said. `And if not hover any item stick active item last hover.`

Comment: @DinhCode what is your expected result when none of them is hovered?

Comment: @Alireza_Ahmadi Same as: if hover item(2) and hover out .thumbs element stick active to item(2). can you help me?

Comment: @DinhCode I updated my answer. you need to keep lastElement. Is it what you want?